# How to Get Parent Radio Group of the checked Radio Button?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I retrieve radio group of the radio button that is checked? I have two radio groups with some radio buttons and I would like to know which group they belong to.

```
void populateSpinner(@ArrayRes int radioId, RadioGroup radioGroup) {
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(SecondActivity.this,
            radioId, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spn_districts.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onRadioButtonClick(View view)
{
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.radio_1:
            if (checked)
                populateSpinner(R.array.radio_1_array, <RADIO BUTTON GROUP>);
            break;
// so on
```

How can I get the Radio Button Group?

Comment: `view.getParent()` ?

Comment: hi Tushar , chech the answer below it has solution for you mate ,

Comment: both (RadioGroup) view.getParent() and radioGroup.getTag() methods worked. Thanks.

Comment: i am glad , being able to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set **tag** for each of your **RadioGroup** in your xml code , and when you click any RadioButton, you can get the Parent RadioGroup's Tag and easily you can identify the parent **RadioGroup**

**Your activity_layout XML code**

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="FirstRadioGroup"
        android:id="@+id/firstRG">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="one"
            android:id="@+id/firstRB"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="two"
            android:id="@+id/secondRB"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```

**JAVA Activity Code**

```
 RadioGroup firstRG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.firstRG);
       firstRG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
             switch(i){
                 case R.id.firstRB:
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Parent RadioGroup is --"+radioGroup.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     break;
                 case R.id.secondRB:
                     break;
             }

            }
        });
```

**Like this when you will check the first RadioButton it will show you the Prent RadioGroup Tag Value**